# как unix timestamp перевести в обычную дату/время при получения данных из телеграм бота в google таблицу

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot, telegram, google-spreadsheet, google-docs

пишу телеграм бота, данные из которого приходят в google таблицу.
время приходит в unix timestamp. не понимаю как перевести время в формат 10.12.2022 12:37

```
 function doPost(e) {
  let contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  let chat_id = contents.message.chat.id;
  let text = contents.message.text;
  let date = contents.message.date;
  sendtext(chat_id, text);
  SpreadsheetApp.openById("1wCem9WbY-e7_wfdmLghgshPgрP3пВuddfgрeпVGfdqdDiz71HE_-aKJaQzmf0").getSheetByName("messsages").appendRow([date, text]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

сама решила, кому может понадобится:

```
function time(s) {
    return new Date(s * 1e3).toISOString().slice(-13, -5);
}
console.log( time(12345) );
```